# Code works for FirefoxDriver but NOT in HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: webdriver, htmlunit, selenium-firefoxdriver

I need to click on a link pointed by following xPath : html/body/div[2]/ul/li[9]/a (generated using firepath) The corresponding Html snippes is as following :
**< a href="/abb/logout">Logoff**

My code is like this :

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver= new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
WebElement logoffElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
    .until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>(){
        @Override
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
      return d.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/ul/li[9]/a"));
    }});

logoffElement.click();
```

The above code is working for Firefoxdriver but not in HtmlUnitdriver. HtmlUnitdriver gives following error :

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate a node using html/body/div[2]/ul/li[9]/a
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.21.0', revision: '16552', time: '2012-04-11 19:08:38'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_23'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElementByXPath(HtmlUnitDriver.java:802)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:344)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$5.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$5.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.implicitlyWaitFor(HtmlUnitDriver.java:984)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:396)
    at com.nike.automation.Task$1.apply(Task.java:70)
    at com.nike.automation.Task$1.apply(Task.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:201)
```

Comment: Enable javaScript hence solved my problem. But facing new one "FailingHttpStatusCodeException - Too much redirect for ..", is catching error for Status code 302 important, does it make sense ? Again FirefoxDriver has no such problem but HtmlUnit is facing it. I feel lost... please help..

Answer (score 0):

HtmlUnitDriver is a fake browser, which can't handle javascript and lacks of features which normal browsers have. FirefoxDriver or ChromeDriver use real browsers.

Answer (score 0):

//html/body/div[2]/ul/li[9]/a -- Absolute XPath.

It is not advisable to use Absolute XPath. Use Relative XPath so that it will be working in all browsers.

Thanks!